# Remove/ truncate leading zeros by javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, zero

Suggest solution for removing or truncating leading zeros from number(any string) by javascript,jquery.

Comment: what should happen when string is "000000000"

Comment: Is the number expected to be an integer always, or it should handle numbers with decimals (e.g. `'00000.5'`)?

Comment: it should give work for any string given. i.e. "00000evsdd" should give "evsdd", "00000.5" should give ".5"

Comment: @robert: about your question: what should happen when string is "000000000"? It must return "0". Otherwise, it would imply an additional logic.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

You can use a regular expression that matches zeroes at the beginning of the string:

```
s = s.replace(/^0+/, '');
```

Comment: @Guffa:I am using it in jquery code..may be because of that it might not working.

Comment: @Somnath, jQuery IS javascript.  If something works in javascript it will continue to work if you happen to be using jQuery as well.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: s = s.replace(/^0+/, '') will convert "00" to in "" (empty string instead of string with one zero in), which in most cases is undesirable, better encapsulate it in a function and add the line: if (s == "") s = "0";

Comment: This regex has an issue if you have all zeros, `"0000"`. The issue can be fixed with positive lookahead: `.replace(/^0+/, '')`

Comment: What is about if we have 0.45 and I want to keep at least one 0?

Comment: @yasserpulido use `parseFloat`, e.g. `parseFloat("000000.45")[.toString()]`

Answer (score 47):

I would use the Number() function:

```
var str = "00001";
str = Number(str).toString();
```

```
>> "1"
```

Or I would multiply my string by 1

```
var str = "00000000002346301625363";
str = (str * 1).toString();
```

```
>> "2346301625363"
```

Comment: it will not work with value bigger than 2^53. Number("009007199254740993").toString() will be "9007199254740992"

Comment: @madreason do you think your example could possibly be a use case? So a medium test would be needed? If so, I agree with you, my first bullet answer is not right

Answer (score 17):

Maybe a little late, but I want to add my 2 cents.

if your string ALWAYS represents a number, with possible leading zeros, you can simply cast the string to a number by using the '+' operator.

e.g.

```
x= "00005";
alert(typeof x); //"string"
alert(x);// "00005"

x = +x ; //or x= +"00005"; //do NOT confuse with x+=x, which will only concatenate the value
alert(typeof x); //number , voila!
alert(x); // 5 (as number)
```

if your string doesn't represent a number and you only need to remove the 0's use the other solutions, but if you only need them as number, this is the shortest way.

and FYI you can do the opposite, force numbers to act as strings if you concatenate an empty string to them, like:

```
x = 5;
alert(typeof x); //number
x = x+"";
alert(typeof x); //string
```

hope it helps somebody

Comment: it will not work with value bigger than 2^53. (+"009007199254740993").toString() will be "9007199254740992"

Comment: This is a very clean solution when working with small numbers. Thanks for this tip, person from 2013! =D

Answer (score 14):

Since you said "any string", I'm assuming this is a string you want to handle, too.

```
"00012  34 0000432    0035"
```

So, regex is the way to go:

```
var trimmed = s.replace(/\b0+/g, "");
```

And this will prevent loss of a "000000" value.

```
var trimmed = s.replace(/\b(0(?!\b))+/g, "")
```

You can see a [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/SWbDe/)

Answer (score 6):

```
parseInt(value) or parseFloat(value)
```

This will work nicely.

Comment: Not for decimals though

Comment: @sburke0708 - Yes it will? That's what the parseFloat does.

Comment: Great one, Helped me

Answer (score 3):

I got this solution for truncating leading zeros(number or any string) in javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function trimNumber(s) {
  while (s.substr(0,1) == '0' && s.length>1) { s = s.substr(1,9999); }
  return s;
}

var s1 = '00123';
var s2 = '000assa';
var s3 = 'assa34300';
var s4 = 'ssa';
var s5 = '121212000';

alert(s1 + '=' + trimNumber(s1));
alert(s2 + '=' + trimNumber(s2));
alert(s3 + '=' + trimNumber(s3));
alert(s4 + '=' + trimNumber(s4));
alert(s5 + '=' + trimNumber(s5));
// end hiding contents -->
</script>
```

Comment: That's not very good code. The check for the string length is totally superflous, it will never be evaluated to `false`. The use of `9999` as the second parameter to `substr` is not needed. Just use `while (s.substr(0,1) == '0') s = s.substr(1);`. Besides, that code snippet looks really old, the `language` attribute of the `script` tag has been deprecated for a long time, and using comments inside `script` tags is only needed for browsers that doesn't understand the `script` tag at all, e.g. Internet Explorer 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

Simply try to multiply by one as following:

> "00123" * 1;              // Get as number
>   
>   "00123" * 1 + "";       // Get as string

Answer (score 3):

**1.** The most explicit is to use parseInt():

```
parseInt(number, 10)
```

**2.** Another way is to use the + unary operator:

```
+number
```

**3.** You can also go the regular expression route, like this:

```
number.replace(/^0+/, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
   function ltrim(str, chars) {
        chars = chars || "\\s";
        return str.replace(new RegExp("^[" + chars + "]+", "g"), "");
    }

    var str =ltrim("01545878","0");
```

More [here](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-trim.html)

Comment: it is having problem for string value given

Comment: @SomnathMuluk:what problem. here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/AxeUU/

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "radix" parameter of the "parseInt" function :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FparseInt

parseInt('015', 10) => 15

if you don't use it, some javascript engine might use it as an octal
parseInt('015') => 0

Answer (score 1):

If number is int use

```
"" + parseInt(str)
```

If the number is float use

```
"" + parseFloat(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

const number = '0000007457841';
console.log(+number) //7457841;

OR number.replace(/^0+/, '')

Answer (score 1):

Regex solution from [Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8276474/689893), but leaving at least one character

```
"123".replace(/^0*(.+)/, '$1'); // 123
"012".replace(/^0*(.+)/, '$1'); // 12
"000".replace(/^0*(.+)/, '$1'); // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to remove all leading zeros for every sequence of digits in a string and to return 0 if the digit value equals to zero.

And I ended up doing so:

```
str = str.replace(/(0{1,}\d+)/, "removeLeadingZeros('$1')")

function removeLeadingZeros(string) {
    if (string.length == 1) return string
    if (string == 0) return 0
    string = string.replace(/^0{1,}/, '');
    return string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One another way without regex:

```
function trimLeadingZerosSubstr(str) {
    var xLastChr = str.length - 1, xChrIdx = 0;
    while (str[xChrIdx] === "0" && xChrIdx < xLastChr) {
        xChrIdx++;
    }
    return xChrIdx > 0 ? str.substr(xChrIdx) : str;
}
```

With short string it will be more faster than regex ([jsperf](http://jsperf.com/trim-leading-zeros))

Answer (score 0):

```
const input = '0093';
const match = input.match(/^(0+)(\d+)$/);
const result = match && match[2] || input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "Math.abs"

eg: Math.abs(003) = 3;

```js
console.log(Math.abs(003))
```

Answer (score 0):

Now here you can remove all the front 0 from any string without removing 0's inside that string

```
let asd = '0000SD1008009023';
do {
  asd=asd.substring(1,asd.length);
} while(asd[0]==0)
'SD1008009023'
```