# How do I remove the content on my input field with jquery if the value is 0, 00, 000 and so on?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a price field that only allows the use of numbers. I use the following code in the head:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('#item_price').keyup(function () { 
       this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    });
});
```

and this is my field:

```
<input type="text" minlength="2" id="item_price" name="item_price">
```

What i'm trying to do now is force the field to be empty if the person types in 0 or 00 or 000 and so on... but without messing up with numbers that contain 0 but are actually a specific price (for example 300, 10250, 10).

Is there any way that i can accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276451/remove-truncate-leading-zeros-by-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
jQuery('#item_price').keyup(function () { 
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
  this.value = this.value.replace(/^[0]+/g,'');
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PmVPg/)

Answer (score 4):

Try checking if the value is the number `0`.

```
if(parseInt(this.value, 10) === 0){
    this.value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#item_price').keyup(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (/^0+$/.test($this.val()) {
            $this.val('');
        }
    });
});
```