# JS remove leading zeros

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, math

In JavaScript, I want to remove the decimal place & the following zeros.

For example, my original number: "0.00558", I want to be left with "558".

Is this possible? (I'm also using AngularJS if that has a method for this).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate leading zeros of a string in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594325/truncate-leading-zeros-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove/ truncate leading zeros by javascript/jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276451/remove-truncate-leading-zeros-by-javascript-jquery)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as it does something more than just truncating the non-mantisse part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do that by a simple regex replace.

```
var number = "0.00558";
number = number.replace(/^[0\.]+/, "");
console.log(number);//number is now "558"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the decimal point:

```
el.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
```

or

```
el.value.replace(/\./g,'');
```

Then get the integer value:

```
var el.value = parseInt(el.value);
```

While I have always gone with the default radix being 10, @aduch makes a good point.  And MDN concurs.

The safer way is:

```
var el.value = parseInt(el.value,10);
```

**From MDN:**
    If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16 (hexadecimal) and the remainder of the string is parsed.
    If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  **ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet.  For this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt.**
    If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).

Comment: `parseInt` should be given a radix (i.e. 10)

Comment: @aduch yes I that is the best practice, but it also works without the radix. I think if you don't give up a radix it defaults to 10.

Comment: @aduch you are correct.  Edited post to reflect your comment.