# regular expression for validating fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Validations i'm trying :

- regular expression of : 9999.99 and no spaces (0009.99 it should convert 9.99

Edit :

```
var regex = '(?!0)\d+(?:\.\d+)?$';

function getValue()  {
    // passing value 0009.99 and 0009.00 and 100
    return document.getElementById("myinput").value;

}

function test() {
    alert(regex.test(getValue()));
}

function match() {
    alert(getValue().match(regex));    
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8276451/1596138

Answer (score 4):

Your first and second seems to Work just fine, the third can be achieved with the following regex:

```
/(?!0)\d+\.\d+$/
```

It starts by looking forward for zeros (skipping them), then it matches any number of digits followed by a dot and more digits. If you want the digits to be optional you can replace the plus '`+`' with a star '`*`'.

**Edit**:

If you want to allow integers, you can use this regex:

```
/(?!0)\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/
```

That makes the dot and the digits after that optional.

BTW: Your jsfiddle does not help in answering.

**Edit2**:

To create a Regex using quotes you must use the following syntax:

```
var regex = new RegExp('(?!0)\d+(?:\.\d+)?$');
```

**Edit3**:

I forgot to mention, you need to double escape backslashes, it should be:

```
var regex = new RegExp('(?!0)\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$');
```

Now it should Work directly in your code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u6Lctkw9/1/ - it is not working ! i wanted to add only "12" price.

Comment: that regular expression is not working in angular/javascript. what do you recommend?

Comment: Sure it does, just make sure you don't quote the regex when you use slashes.

Comment: What's the problem? It matches the number as it should skipping the zeros.