# How can I convert a time into the correct format?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to convert time from the format.
I want to get the following effect, for example:
`03 s -> 3s`;
`01 h 04 m 05 s -> 1 h 4 m 5 s`;
`01h -> 1h`;
`01h 15 m 07 s -> 1h 15 m 7 s`

I use library timelite / time.

```
 let time = 00:00:03
 let a = add(time);
 let b = str(a);

 convert = (time) => {
    const [hour, minute, sec] = time.split(':');

    if (hour !== "00") {
      return `${hour} h ${minute} m ${sec} s`;
    }

    if (minute !== "00") {
      return `${minute} m ${sec} s`;
    }

    return `${sec} s`;
  }

console.log(convert(b))  //output 03s
```

Comment: @Heretic Monkey  It isn't duplicate. My example: 02:02:02 --> my output 2:2:2. Yours post  "Remove leading zeros from time format "  delete only first  0 --> 2:02:02

Comment: @ScottMarcus Maybe [Remove/ truncate leading zeros by javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8276451/215552) would be more appropriate. The OP could run that on each of `[hour, minute, sec]`.

Comment: No clue helped me. I'm using `replace (/ ^ 0 + /, '')` on hours, minutes, sec. I remove zero. But if I have for example: 02 h 00 m 07s this is a defect 2h m 7s. The letter `m` remains

Comment: If you are using momentjs, this may help you: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/